# Relation between Last digits of $(5p \pm q)^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know it's too easy to found last digits of $p^q$,since they keep repeating. People also use mod/fermat theorem , which i haven't study yet. I don't know if it is useful or not. But still i want to share .

Comment: mod is mostly talking in terms of lines with integer slope and integer y intercept and only talking about points on the line evaluated at integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let take a look last digit of squares from 0 to 10.

0,1,4,9,6,5,6,9,4,1,0 .

They are repeating itself around 5. we can say $(5p \pm q)^2$ both have same last digit. where p & q are integers.
We can easily proof it. Let $ D=(5p+q)^2-(5p-q)^2=10p(2q)$ . so D has last digit zero which is only possible if $5p \pm q$ have same digits.
We can generalize it of any even power 2n.
$$(5p+q)^{2n}-(5p-q)^{2n}=[10p .[\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{(-1)}^k.(5p+q)^k.(5p-q)^{n-1-k}].{[(5p+q)^n-(5p-q)^n]}]$$

Now take a look on last digits of cubes from 0 to 10 ,

0,1,8,7,4,5,6,3,2,9,0

As we can see pattern that sum of last digits of $5p \pm q$  is $10 $ or $0$.
 .Proof : since $(5p+q)^3+(5p-q)^3=[(10p)(25p^2+q^2-10pq)]$.
We can generalize it for any odd power 2n+1.

$$[(5p+q)^{2n+1}+(5p-q)^{2n+1}]=[(5p+q)+(5p-q)].[\sum_{k=0}^{2n}(-1)^{k}(5p+q)^k.(5p-q)^{2n-k}]$$.